# Extract decompression part from jpeglib

Tags: c, jpeg, decode, libjpeg

I am trying to extract the part of decompression in the libjpeg to add it to embedded project so i should take the minimum size of code , but i think the code is very complex, do you have any idea how to exclude this part from the library ? and is there another way , i want to decompress the jpeg photo the return form camera to make pattern recognition on it. any ideas ???

Comment: Is your embedded device really so cramped that you need to trim down the library? ie, have you actually tried to simply include the library and use it?

Comment: the problem is that the embedded board haven't enough ROM space to include all the library

Answer (score 4):

[libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty well-optimized library, it is ported to a number of architectures.

if this library takes too much resources, I would recommend you to take a look at others similar libraries:

https://code.google.com/p/picojpeg/

> picojpeg is a public domain JPEG decompressor written in plain C in a
> single source file picojpeg.c and a single header picojpeg.h. It has
> several fairly unique properties that make it useful on small 8/16-bit
> embedded devices or in very memory constrained environments:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/libjpeg-turbo/

> libjpeg-turbo is a derivative of libjpeg that uses MMX, SSE, SSE2, and
> NEON SIMD instructions to accelerate baseline JPEG
> compression/decompression by about 2-4x on x86, x86-64, and ARM
> platforms. It is based on libjpeg/SIMD but has numerous enhancements.

Hope it helps !

Comment: when i compiled this library using visual studio 2010 it make app.sln which contain solution -> (djpeg , cjpeg , jpegtran, rdjpgcom,wrjpgcom) ,, every project of them contain its files , i interested in djpeg which contain cderror.h cdjpeg.h jconfig.h jerror.h jinclude.h jmorecfg.h jpeglib.h jversion.h cdjpeg.c djpeg.c rdcolmap.c wrbmp.c wrgif.c wrppm.c wrrle.c wrtarga.c )) i need to compile these files in a single project but i always get errors like linker errors , undefined refrences ... etc any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Tearing apart a library like that to trim it down is a noble effort, the sort of project fork which would make a... say... minimalized jpeg library. minjpeglib.  Or smaller. Let's go [nano](http://keyj.emphy.de/nanojpeg/). Yeah, the thing is that this has been done. [Quite a lot.](http://code.google.com/p/jpgd/) You may have some issues with them as they probably don't contain all the features that the jpeg format is capable of. So some images may not load, and some images may not load quite right.

If you want full support, well, there's a reason that jpeglib is so large and complex.

If you really want to tear into jpeglib, I really don't know where to begin but I can give some broad advice. Comb through it for some specific function you want. Trace it's dependencies. What all structures it uses, what helper functions, and what headers. Copy over the portions to a new folder adding bits until you have a program that compiles and runs. Unfortunately, I have no guarantee that it won't include most or all of the original jpeglib.

Ack! Beat out by Mr. Wizzard!

Comment: when i compiled this library using visual studio 2010 it make app.sln which contain solution -> (djpeg , cjpeg , jpegtran, rdjpgcom,wrjpgcom) ,, every project of them contain its files , i interested in djpeg which contain 
cderror.h
cdjpeg.h
jconfig.h
jerror.h
jinclude.h
jmorecfg.h
jpeglib.h
jversion.h


cdjpeg.c
djpeg.c
rdcolmap.c
wrbmp.c
wrgif.c
wrppm.c
wrrle.c
wrtarga.c

))

i need to  compile these files in a single project but i always get errors like linker errors , undefined refrences ... etc 


any ideas